# how to install the "Make" command in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, gnu-make

I have been trying to install the command "make" in Windows but I couldn't.
I tried with cygwin and GNU, but I think I am making something wrong somewhere.
Can anyone give me some detailed steps please !

Comment: You should show what you've tried, then people can point out where you went wrong.  Also specify if you're trying to install a pre-compiled version of GNU make, and if so where you got it from, or compile it yourself, in which case what commands you're using to do so.

Answer (score 0):

make is available as package in cygwin. It is not one of the base package so you need to require setup to install it.

See User Guide at:
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: Thanks I installed it following the steps !